# Cache files always created with wrong permissions in Yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

I get this error in my log files every time a cache file doesn't exist it seems. On the first page load, I always get this error

```
[message] => filemtime(): stat failed for [...]/runtime/cache/my/myapp03eab921185f7b68bbca50d8debc0dda.bin
[file] => [...]/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/FileCache.php
[line] => 113
```

It doesn't happen anymore on next page loads but that one time is really annoying since the slack bot watcher is spamming our channel with this useless warning. Is there a way to avoid that, or is it a permission problem?

The "runtime", "cache" and "my" folders all have 775.

**Update**
Turns out the issue is that I'm using `error_get_last()` that is also getting warning-level errors. So it's a different issue entirely, not Yii-related

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have enabled [`scream`](http://php.net/manual/en/scream.configuration.php) in your `php.ini`. Warnings from this `filemtime()` call should be suppressed by `@` operator, but `scream` setting can override this operator and generate warning anyway.

```
if (@filemtime($cacheFile) > time()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, never heard about that, thanks for the suggestion, I get this: ini_get('scream.enabled'): FALSE... so it seems it's something else, might be because I'm using error_get_last() and it could grab warnings ignored by @

Comment: @Bobs Try print `phpinfo()` and search for non-default values for error settings.

Comment: Yeah I just checked and error_get_last() catches everything.. so Yii isn't the issue here

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting this in PHP 7.1. try to run this with PHP 5.5 and see if you are getting the same error.

To reproduce you need to delete all files from runtime/cache directory
Then start app again(reload page) and look into runtime/cache. It is empty
Yii2 doesn't make cache again

Comment: Thanks, I've found the "issue" actually, I'm using error_get_last() to send to our Slack channel and it's getting warning as well.. Not sure what to do now as I can't delete my question since there are answers posted

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue in Yii. The error was on the same string (FileCache.php:113)

`if (@filemtime($cacheFile) > time()) {...`

In my case reason was that my custom php error handler (heir 
of the class yii\base\ErrorHandler) didn't check if 
error type need to be handled according error_reporting().

Custom handlers allways gets every error, even muted by Error Control operator (@)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

> error_reporting() settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless